# ¿Para qué sirve la etiqueta [texto] en C#?

Tags: c#, .net

Mi duda es para qué sirve la línea `[texto]` que se pone al inicio de un método o una clase, por ejemplo:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
}
```

¿Qué es lo que hace, cómo se llama o cómo se define?

Comment: Son atributos: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/index

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Como bien dice Asier, esos elementos son conocidos como [Atributos](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/index). Esta duda que planteas creo que puede ser recurrente, así que resumo parte de la información existente sobre el tema en [los docs de microsoft](http://docs.microsoft.com) para que pueda ser útil también a otros, y aprovecho para recomendar buscar siempre información en ese sitio sobre cualquier duda del lenguaje que nos surja.

Los atributos son una especie de metadatos, una información sobre el elemento al que "decoran" y que luego puede ser consultado en tiempo de ejecución mediante `Reflection`.

> Los atributos tienen las propiedades siguientes:
>
> - Los atributos agregan metadatos al programa. Los metadatos son información sobre los tipos definidos en un programa. Todos los
>     ensamblados .NET contienen un conjunto de metadatos específico que
>     describe los tipos y miembros de tipo definidos en el ensamblado.
>     Puede agregar atributos personalizados para especificar cualquier
>     información adicional que sea necesaria. Para obtener más información,
>     vea Crear atributos personalizados (C#).
> - Puede aplicar uno o más atributos a todos los ensamblados, módulos o elementos de programa más pequeños como clases y propiedades.
> - Los atributos pueden aceptar argumentos de la misma manera que los métodos y las propiedades.
> - El programa puede examinar sus propios metadatos o los metadatos de otros programas mediante la reflexión. Para obtener más información,
>     consulte Acceder a atributos mediante reflexión (C#).

Usos comunes de los atributos

> - Marcar métodos con el atributo WebMethod en los servicios
>     web para indicar que el método debe ser invocable a través del
>     protocolo SOAP.
> - Describir cómo serializar parámetros de método al
>     interoperar con código nativo.
> - Describir las propiedades COM para clases, métodos
>     e interfaces.
> - Llamar al código no administrado mediante la clase
>     DllImportAttribute.
> - Describir los ensamblados en cuanto a título,
>     versión, descripción o marca.
> - Describir qué miembros de una clase
>     serializar para la persistencia.
> - Describir cómo realizar asignaciones
>     entre los miembros de clase y los nodos XML para la serialización XML.
> - Describir los requisitos de seguridad para los métodos.
> - Especificar
>     las características utilizadas para reforzar la seguridad.
> - Controlar
>     optimizaciones mediante el compilador Just-In-Time (JIT) para que el
>     código siga siendo fácil de depurar.
> - Obtener información sobre el
>     llamador de un método.